# Resize controls in MDI child

Tags: c#, resize, mdi

I have a mainform that contains a panel in which different MDI child forms are displayed. The controls in the MDI child got Anchor = Left, Right, Top, Bottom to resize.
The problem is the resizing of the controls in the MDI child when the main form is resized. I got it working with the following code:

```
    private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form f in panel.Controls.OfType<Form>())
        {
            f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the controls in the MDI child permanantly change their location when you are resizing. Is there some way to call a Resize method?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  It sounds like you shouldn't be using MDI to begin with since your "forms" are being used as controls in a panel.  Setting the anchors should be good enough.

Comment: You are right, it makes no sense this is only a temporary solution. But i have about 100 different forms to be displayed in the panel so i started using MDI children. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear why the anchor property wouldn't work (or just Dock.Fill).  Displaying 100 different forms - all at once?

Comment: The problem is that the MDI child does not change it's size. So why would the anchor property work? 100 different forms are not displayed at once, but still in the same panel.

Comment: Based on your posted code, your forms aren't really forms.  You must have TopLevel = false in these forms since they are all child controls belonging to the panel.Controls collection.  Make sure to set the BorderStyle to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who got the same issue:
You need to set the Dock property to DockStyle.Fill for the MDI child. Else it just doesn't resize the controls.